How is the argument (#1) in \DeclareNameWrapperFormat interpretted?
I'm trying to generate part of my CV from a bib file, using the biblatex-cv package, which introduces a new entry type called 'degree'. 'degree' has a 'advisor' field, which holds a name list. For each degree, I want to print 'Supervisor' or 'Supervisors', depending on the length of the list, then the name list in the advisor field. I have written a name wrapper which tests the length of the list and prints a singular or plural form as appropriate -- this part works. I am aware that the name list itself is printed (from with the wrapper format) using the argument #1. My problem is that however I write the wrapper, #1 expands to a debug-like name format.
Here's a mwe:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
  datamodel=biblatex-cv,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Degree{onesupervisor,
        date = {2024},
        institution = {University of Texas at Austin},
        degree = {MA},
        advisor = {Smith, John}
}
@Degree{twsupervisors,
        date = {2023},
        institution = {University of Texas at Austin},
        degree = {BA},
        advisor = {Jones, Jack and Doe, Jane}
}
\end{filecontents}

% This correctly tests for Plurals
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{advisor}{%
  \printtext{\ifnumgreater{\value{listtotal}}{1}{Supervisors}{Supervisor}%
      \addcolon\addspace}#1}
  
% I have tried including either of these lines -- neither makes any difference 
% \DeclareNameAlias{advisor}{default}
% \DeclareNameAlias{advisor}{given-family}

\newbibmacro{advisor}{%
  \printnames{advisor}}
% this is equivalent to \printnames[advisor]{advisor}, which calls the
% above format explicitly.

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{degree}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{advisor}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography{}

\end{document}

This compiles to:

What I want is for the names to print as in the default style: 'John Smith', 'Jane Doe', etc.
What am I doing wrong?

The name wrapper format (same for field and list wrappers) is used during \printnames (\printfield, \printlist) to format the complete printed output. The idea is that you can apply formatting like \mkbibemph here or that you could locally redefine a couple of commands.
As you've seen you cannot nest more complex biblatex commands like \printtext inside the wrapper. This does not work because within the wrapper they come in at a point where their effects are not properly protected from interfering with the \print... command in which they are called.
You don't need \printtext here and the following will work just fine
\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{advisor}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{listtotal}}{1}{Supervisors}{Supervisor}%
  \addcolon\addspace#1}

I'd probably find the following solution without name wrappers more idiomatic (mainly because most biblatex styles have been around since before wrappers were a thing and they use something like this idiom).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
  datamodel=biblatex-cv,
]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{supervisor}
\NewBibliographyString{supervisors}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  supervisor = {supervisor},
  supervisors = {supervisors},
}

\newbibmacro{advisor}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{listtotal}}{1}
    {\bibstring{supervisor}}
    {\bibstring{supervisors}}
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \printnames{advisor}}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{degree}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{advisor}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@degree{onesupervisor,
  date        = {2024},
  institution = {University of Texas at Austin},
  degree      = {MA},
  advisor     = {Smith, John},
}
@degree{twsupervisors,
  date        = {2023},
  institution = {University of Texas at Austin},
  degree      = {BA},
  advisor     = {Jones, Jack and Doe, Jane},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}

